# Issue with Boxplot formula or variable definition

Tags: r, plot

I have a csv file having 4 columns labeled AGE, DIASTOLIC, BMI and EVER.PREGNANT and 700 rows. The last column consists of only yes or no. I wish to plot the data BMI vs EVER.PREGNANT with an intent to comparing BMI of those with yes in the fourth column and no in the same column. What code should I write to get the required boxplot?
I have tried the following code:

```
Sheet=read.csv(/Downloads/1739230_1284354330_PIMA.csv - 1739230_1284354330_PIMA.csv.csv, sep=",")
boxplot(BMI~EVER.PREGNANT,data=sheet, main="BMI vs PREG",xlab="BMI",ylab="PREGNANT")
```

The error that I get is

`Error in eval(expr,envr,enclos): object 'Sheet' not found`

Similarly, what modifications can be done to plot AGE vs DIASTOLIC, where both columns are numbers? Will I get the 700 odd values nicely?

Comment: You copied the function again, not the error appearing :-)

Comment: @R18 modified the error

Comment: It doesn't recognize the `Sheet` object. Be careful with capital letters. What does it appear if you write `head(Sheet)` or `head(sheet)` ?

Comment: ok, after correcting the capitalization, I get the error 'BMI' not found

Comment: Which is the output of `colnames(sheet)`?

Comment: @R18 [1] "X"   "X.1" "X.2" "X.3" "X.4"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I answer here because it tells me not to extend the discussion :-).

I think you haven't loaded correctly your data set. You need to add `header = T` when loading to tell the program that your first row corresponds with the names of the variables.

```
Sheet=read.csv("/Downloads/1739230_1284354330_PIMA.csv", sep=",", header = T)
```

Comment: tried your code, again the same error: eval(expr,envir,enclos):object 'BMI' not found

Comment: Now, what does it appear when you write `colnames(sheet)`?

Comment: The same as before; "X", "X.1","X.2","X.3","X.4"

Comment: There is still the problem. It shouldn't appear if you added `header=T`. Without acces to the data is difficilut to give the correct answer :-(. Also remember that the name of the file need to be writen between `""` and your file ends with `.csv.csv` while just one ".csv" has to be there.

Comment: shall I upload the link to csv file?

Comment: It would be helpful

Comment: here is the csv file:[CSV](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B_NO-N-VZuNiRDV2ZnVXZ3FGWHc)

Comment: I can't load in a correct way. On the top of the file it appears the word PRIMA.csv alone and then the name of variables are mixed with html code. Can you obtain the data in a better way without these problems?

Comment: here is the modified file which i used, but with no result:[CSV](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B_NO-N-VZuNiMEhfenduc3VkMGs)

Comment: Thanks, solved the problem. Though the colnames(Sheet) returns the same output, but boxplot(Sheet) produces a decent plot. Would be better if that also could be solved.